# jquery animate a div to the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
          <div id="animate">
        cartagena
      </div>
        </div>
```

what I want to do is to move the "animated" div to the center using Jquery.

my current js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#animate").animate({left: "+=512"}, 2000); 
});
```

and now I'd like to make it to the center instead of just 512 px to the right.

Comment: To the center of what? #header, #container, document, window?

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming that the position of `#animate` is `absolute`. To center the element in its parent element just add the half of its parent's width minus the half of its own width to `left`:

```
$("#animate").animate({
    left: $("#animate").parent().width() / 2 - $("#animate").width() / 2
}, 2000);
```

I created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gJAa/) using jsFiddle.

Comment: @WouterVandenputte It should behave the same on a browser refresh... Anyway, you could try to [set the left value](http://jsfiddle.net/8gJAa/1/) before animating.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it this way to center it to the screen,

***Jquery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#animate").animate({left: $(window).width() / 2}, 2000);
});
```

***css***

```
<style type="text/css">
div
{
     height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: Red;position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}
</style>
```

***html***

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="animate">
            cartagena
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Asuming you want to center to window, use this code:

```
$("#myJQUIDialog").parent().position({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window,
    using: function (pos, ext) {
        $(this).animate({ top: pos.top }, 600);
    }
});
```

This center the dialog, and animate at the same time, resulting in a smooth centering

Answer (score -2):

Here it is other example, maybe it should be useful.
I am using 'scroll' to make the effects.

Hope it could help or be useful :)...

`<http://jsfiddle.net/p609dm7y/2/>`

Comment: Sorry, for downvoting, but your answer does not anything useful, in my opinion. There are already three valid answers including a jsFiddle demo. If you provide code snippets, please make sure they demonstrate what the OP has been asking for.